# Google Sheets Data Source from API (Not BigQuery)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm creating a Google Sheets add-on, in which the user can see their facebook campaigns, and when selecting one, I would like to create a table with some statistics in the sheet.

Google supports a "[DataSourceSpecBuilder](https://developers.google.cn/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-source-spec-builder.html)" which can get data from a third party, and draw it as a table on the sheet, and also saves a state of all data sources, can easily refresh all of them, etc...

This builder seems to only support BigQuery data, but my data comes directly from the facebook API. Is there a way to create a non-BQ data source so I can enjoy all of the infrastructure around data sources and not customly write it?

Comment: Based on the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases#february_26_2019) `DataSourceSpecBuilder` is one of a new set of Classes whose sole purpose is to support BigQuery integration with Google Sheets. Looks like you'll have to build out your own infrastructure to support the Facebook API yourself...

Comment: "table with some statistics in the sheet" - what stats did you have in mind, are they accessible from the Facebook API. Would `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` be applicable?

Comment: @Tedinoz While getting the data (with `UrlFetchApp`) is trivial, Google has a data structure that can save the report parameters, such that the user can easily refresh all of their reports. I have to save all of the parameters myself, and code my own refresh

Comment: Apologies, I see what you mean. As a matter of interest, do you have a source for this: "_which can get data from a third party, and draw it as a table on the sheet, and also saves a state of all data sources, can easily refresh all of them, etc..._" As Dimu Designs noted, the Release notes refer only to BigQuery

Comment: @Tedinoz That is what their base interface is theoretically for, support for any data source. Unfortunately, they only implemented BigQuery and I don't seem to have access to implement something of my own.